# How to make code completion faster in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Is there any tweaks you'd made or third party add-in installed to improve the performance of the Delphi 2010 Code Completion? I find it very slow compared to the Code Completion of Delphi 7.

Comment: You could write less code! ;-)

Comment: I disagree. Delphi7 code completion would freeze my Delphi for about 20~30 seconds. It was a productivity bottleneck. Anyway you could try CnPack www.cnpack.org which has a custom code completion (which I actually find completely useless in Delphi2010, but maybe you like it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[IDE Fix Pack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=246) may help, it has some general fixes for IDE.

Comment: +1 Andy recently migrated some of the Delphi Speed Up code to the Fix Pack

Answer (score 0):

I had a very serious issue with speed, in *delphi* *XE5* and *Xe6*. until I uninstalled `cnPack` and installed `IDE Fix Pack`. Problem solved.